# Will my join remove my relate?

Tags: arcmap, attribute-joins, arcgis-10.5, relates

I have spatial data that has an existing related table with photo info.
I have data from another separate table that I want to join and then field calculate to add to my spatial data, then I would remove the joined table.

I checked Esri's site for information and here is advice they offered.

"Relate tableB to layerC, then join tableA to layerC: This scenario does not work. This is different from the previous scenario in that layerC owns the relate. Therefore, when tableA is joined to layerC, the relate is removed.

Relates owned by the join table are not affected by the join. These relates can't be accessed by the target table or layer, however.
 Relationship classes are never removed as a result of a join or unjoin operation. They can be used regardless of whether the data has been involved in joins or relates."

Will my relate be removed? I do not know if my relate is owned by "layerC" or TableB.

Answer (score 1):

Solution found. 
I was able to join tableA to LayerC and add my data then field calculate and unjoin.
Relate was not removed.